# Which states does framebuffer store?

Tags: opengl, framebuffer

I created a off-screen framebuffer and added two render target to it.

Each render target has its own blending mode. I set it by `glBlendFunci`:

```
glBlendFunci(accum->buffId,     GL_ONE,  GL_ONE);
glBlendFunci(revealage->buffId, GL_ZERO, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_COLOR);
```

Does framebuffer stores this blending mode? Because it is specific to a buffer. Should I set this in every frame or just in initialization code?

Also off-screen framebuffer doesn't write to depth so I disabled it by `glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);` but it seems it is global state rather than framebuffer state.

I don't know how many or which states framebuffer stores. Especially I want to know about these states which about framebuffer's attachments:

1. glBlendFunci
2. glBlendFunc
3. glEnable(GL_BLEND)
4. glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
5. glDepthMask

Does framebuffer store any of these states? Also I would like to know other states if you would like to share it.

I know VAO object stores some states about vertex attributes so I thought that maybe framebuffer also stores some states which related to its attachments

EDIT: I updated glBlendFunci parameter to use draw index, I was used bufferId/objectId

```
glBlendFunci(accum->drawIndex,     GL_ONE,  GL_ONE);
glBlendFunci(revealage->drawIndex, GL_ZERO, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_COLOR);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to know what state framebuffer objects deal with is to look at the OpenGL 4.5 DSA-based APIs. Any function of the form `glNamedFramebuffer*` affects a framebuffer object. And if there is no function of that form, then the state behind it does not affect framebuffer state. And therefore, the equivalent non-DSA form also doesn't affect the framebuffer's state.

Notably, there is no `glNamedFramebufferBlendFunc` call. Or `*DepthMask`. Indeed, none of the state you mention are a part of the framebuffer.

> I know VAO object stores some states about vertex attributes so I thought that maybe framebuffer also stores some states which related to its attachments

But that's the thing; these things don't relate to the *attachments* of a framebuffer. It's kind of complicated.

See, when you call `glBlendFunci`, you pass an index. This sets the blending mode for a particular index. If you pass zero, then you modify the [blending mode for index 0](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending#Fragment_Outputs). That index matches the [FS output location 0](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader#Output_buffers).

But index 0 *is not* `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`. It is the [draw buffer index 0](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Draw_Buffer). Depending on what you specified when you called `glNamedFramebufferDrawBuffers`, draw buffer index 0 could refer to `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2`.

Because these indices do not specific framebuffer attachments directly, it would be incorrect to claim that setting blending state directly affects the framebuffer attachment.

Comment: thanks for clarification, obviously I misused `glBlendFunci`, after adding a color attachment I'm setting glDrawBuffers and make indexes identical, but  it doesn't mean I used it correctly, thanks. But I'm confused a bit now, does framebuffer hold `glBlendFunci` state? if state is not set with `glNamed**` that means it is in global context right?

Comment: @recp: As I said, "*Indeed, none of the state you mention are a part of the framebuffer.*" Also, "*if state is not set with glNamed** that means it is in global context right?*" No, that's not what I meant. I mean that if there isn't a DSA function to set it on the framebuffer, then the *equivalent* non-DSA function is not setting framebuffer state.

Comment: I was passed texture objectId to `glBlendFunci` probably this made me confused and I thought that since I'm passing objectId I expect that framebuff must remember this state. Passing index makes things clear. I edited question